# how to detect toggle with form change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section called UPO with upoCost for the section on a form. I use this code to detect if UPO is visible or not, and hence add/subtract base cost of the section.

```
$("#showUPO").click(function(){
    $("#sectionUPO").toggle();
    if ($("#sectionUPO").is(":hidden")){
        upoCost-=5;
        $("#upoEmailCost").val(upoCost);
    }
    else {
        upoCost+=5;
        $("#upoEmailCost").val(upoCost);
    }
})
```

So the cost for the section is updated every time I click the button, however the total cost for the form is not.

```
$("form").on("change", function(){
    var sum = upoCost; // + other costs;
    $("#reqTotalCost").val(sum);
})
```

I wonder if there's a way to capture it using similar .on("change") methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#upoEmailCost").val(upoCost).trigger('change');
```

Try manually triggering a change event to bubble up to the form.  Logical changes to an element do not inherently generate events.

```
$("#showUPO").click(function(){
    var $upo = $("#sectionUPO").toggle();

    if ($upo.is(":hidden")){
        upoCost-=5;
    } else {
        upoCost+=5;
    }

    $("#upoEmailCost").val(upoCost).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: That works very well. Thank you. Just to clarify on ```trigger('change')``` method, why do I apply it on the ```$("#upoEmailCost").val(upoCost)``` and not ```$("#reqTotalCost").val(sum)```?

Comment: You're changing the value of the upoEmailCost here, no?  That's what changed.  That event will then be caught and handled by the other event handler, which will lead to the total cost being changed, subsequently.

Comment: When I click the button, the value of upoEmailCost changes, yes, but the value of reqTotalCost does not. So shouldnt we trigger reqTotalCost? P.S. I just tested both and both work.

Comment: So long as the element you trigger the change event on is a child of the form, it doesn't really matter.  The important thing is to get the event triggered in the form so it bubbles up to it to be processed. @Biarys